# How to see that $D(\mathscr B)= E(\mathscr B)$ if, in addition, $X$ is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. Let $\mathscr B$ be an open base, consisting of clopen sets, for a space $X$. Put $$D(\mathscr B)= \{S=\langle S_n: n\in \omega\rangle: S \text{ is a sequence of disjoint non-empty sets from } \mathscr B \text{ that has no cluster point in } X\}.$$ We say that $S\in D(\mathscr B)$ is $\mathscr B$-exact if whenever $S$ frequently meets a $B\in \mathscr B$, then $S$ eventually is contained in $B$, i.e., if for every $n$ there exists $n \le m$ such that $S_m\cap B \neq \emptyset$, then there exists $n$ such that $S_m\subseteq B$ for all $n\le m$. Put $E(\mathscr B)=\{S\in D(\mathscr B): S \text{ is } \mathscr {B}-\text{exact}\}$

**Question: How to see that there exists $\mathscr B$ such that $D(\mathscr B)= E(\mathscr B)$ if, in addition, $X$ is locally compact?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky: Thanks. The question should be modified to be that how to see that whether there exists $\mathscr B$ such that $D(\mathscr B)= E(\mathscr B)$ if, in addition, $X$ is locally compact?

Comment: What means “$S$ is a sequence of disjoint non-empty sets from $\mathscr B$ that has no cluster point in $X$? Each point $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that (1) “U intersects only finite number of $S_n$” or (2) “U contains only finite number of $S_n$”?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: It satisfies (1).

Comment: It seems strange.Let $\mathscr B$ be a family of all open (not necessarily clopen) subsets of $X$ with compact closure.Then $\mathscr B$ is a base of $X$. If $S=\{s_n\}$  is a sequence of disjoint non-empty subsets of $X$ (not necessarily from $\mathscr B$) without cluster points in $X$, then $S$ cannot frequently meet any subset $B\in \mathscr B$, because in the opposite case the family $\{S_n\cap\overline{B}\}$ contains infinitely many members which are nonempty subsets of a compact set $\overline{B}$, and therefore the  family $\{S_n\cap\overline{B}\}$ has a cluster point in $\overline{B}$.